# "Book of" tag cleanup

Tags: support, retagging

I was just looking through some of the bible related questions and was wondering if anyone wanted to help cleanup the stuff you get when searching for ["book of"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22book+of%22&submit=search)?

Adding [book-of-revelation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-revelation), etc... and retagging/synonomizing accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few:

[How do Mormons interpret the warning in Revelation about adding to the book?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/609/how-do-mormons-view-the-warning-in-revelation-about-adding-to-the-book) (revelation)

[Who was Theophilus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/who-was-theophilus) (Luke/Acts)

[Who were Jannes and Jambres?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/495/who-were-jannes-and-jambres) (2nd Timothy)

[If Adam and Eve were perfect, why did they choose to sin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1378/if-adam-and-eve-were-perfect-why-did-they-choose-to-sin) (genesis - synonym)

[What is an overview of the main interpretations of "day" in Genesis 1?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/642/what-is-the-specific-meaning-of-day-in-genesis-1) (genesis)

[What is the case for interpreting the Genesis creation account literally?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2939/what-is-the-case-for-interpreting-the-genesis-creation-account-literally) (genesis)

[How is ignoring clear Biblical instructions in Leviticus justified?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30/how-is-ignoring-clear-biblical-instructions-in-leviticus-justified) (leviticus - synonym)

[Do not allow a sorceress/witch to live?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/do-not-allow-a-sorceress-witch-to-live) (exodus)

[What happened to the tribe of Dan in Revelation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/what-happened-to-the-tribe-of-dan-in-revelation) (revelation - synonym)

[How could Jesus be born during the reign of Herod, and when Quirinius was governor of Syria, if those periods were not contemporary?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5645/how-could-jesus-be-born-during-the-reign-of-herod-and-when-quirinius-was-govern) (matthew)

[Who were the "giants" mentioned in the Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/who-were-the-giants-mentioned-in-the-bible) (genesis)

[How does Free Grace Theology reconcile 1 John?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/how-does-free-grace-theology-reconcile-1-john) (1 John)

[Was the flood of Noah global or local?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/649/was-the-flood-of-noah-global-or-local) (genesis)

Answer (score 0):

Also, could we clean up [revelation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revelation) to [book-of-revelation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-revelation) where appropriate (could make synonyms for [revelation-of-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revelation-of-john) or [apocalypse-of-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocalypse-of-john) if they're found)?

Comment: you should be able to suggest a synonym....(if you can't let me know here or in chat)